# bootstrap col position wont show in the beside, always show to the bottom

Tags: php, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, image

sorry if i new to this web programming, why my product display wont show in the beside, and always show to the bottom, im already using col-md-3 to make the prodcut show sideaways, but the product shows in bottom.

[here the picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qWUvN.png)

here my code:

```
  if($result):
if(mysqli_num_rows($result)>0):
  while($product = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)):
  ?>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-4">
    <div class="product">
      <figure>
      <img src=gambar/<?php echo $product['image']; ?> class="img-fluid"/> </figure>
      <p class="text-info text-center"><?php echo $product['namaFran']; ?> </p>
      <p class="text-center"><?php echo $product['deskripsi']; ?> </p><br>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each iteration of your while loop is starting a new row. Place your while loop within it.